# Is there a command to show all fields but selected with Grails Fields Plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Right now, Grails generated the next code:

```
<f:all bean="forestHappyAnimals"/>
```

I want to hide/show some fields with Javascript doing something like:

```
<div id="message-1" onclick="document.getElementById('hideMeId').style.display='none'">Click to hide</div>
<div id="message-2" onclick="document.getElementById('hideMeId').style.display='inline'">Click to show</div>

<div id="hideMeId">
...
</div>
```

If I write the next code, the property `name` appear twice:

```
<f:all bean="forestHappyAnimals"/>

<div id="hideMeId">
    <f:field bean="forestHappyAnimals" property="name"/>
</div>
```

How could I avoid that field repeated? The only way is to write `<f:field bean="...` for all fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use except attribute like describes in [documentation](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/ref/Tags/all.html)

> except - A comma-separated list of properties that should be skipped (in addition to the defaults).

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! I was looking in the documentation but I had the "Tags" of the right hidden, and I didn't realize that clicking on it the tags will appear :)